# How could I prove this basic linear algebraic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am a bachelor in computer science and am learning Г.М.Фихтентольц's *Calculus*,
here is a formula that I can't prove myself and need help.

suppose:

$$
[aa] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2, [ab] = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_ib_i
$$
e.t.c

prove
$$
\left | \begin{matrix} [aa] & [ab]  & [ac] \\ 
[ba] & [bb]  & [bc] \\ [ca] & [cb]  & [cc] \\ \end{matrix} \right | = \sum_{(i,j.k)}\left | \begin{matrix} a_i & b_i  & c_i \\ a_j & b_j & c_j \\ a_k & b_k  & c_k \\ \end{matrix} \right |^2  
$$
where  the sum on the right means every possible 3-ary combination of $(i,j,k)$ from 1 to n

I have tried with specific $n$ (like 1,2,3) in $2 \times 2$ circumstances, and it can be proven by complex but primary calculation. However, for arbitrary $n$ and $3\times 3$ circumstances, I cannot write a general proof to persuade myself. (since $3 \times 3$ determinant is much harder to compute than $2 \times 2$). Does this formula have some kind of meaning to intuitively understand, rather than use brute-force calculation to prove? (I do feel this formula have some symmetrcity)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You might do the problem explicitly for the 2 by 2 case (so only a,b) and get an idea of how it works.

Comment: You can write the first, second, and third rows of your $3\times 3$ matrix as $$a_1v_{1}+\dots+a_nv_{n}$$ $$b_1v_1+\dots +b_nv_n$$ $$c_1v_1+\dots +c_nv_n$$where $v_{j}=(a_j,b_j,c_j)$. Now use the fact that the determinant is a linear transformation on each row of a matrix (while keeping other rows fixed) to get your result.